# Android Studio Emulator getExternalFilesDir() "Permission denied" in Device File Explorer

Tags: android

Android Studio 3.6.3. In my App, getExternalFilesDir() returns "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.birdersdiary.mobile/files".

I want to drop files in that directory so that my App can locate and read the contents of those files in the AVD/emulator.

If I open the Device File Explorer, I cannot browse to that location in order to drop a couple files from my PC into that directory. I get the following:

[image]

In other directories I can drop files from my PC using the popup menu on any given directory.

I can do this on my S9+ phone attached to my PC using Windows File Explorer. Although in Windows File Explorer, the path is shown as "Computer\Galaxy S9+\Phone\Android\data\com.birdersdiary.mobile\files". But in Android Studio's "Device File Explorer" I get the same "Permission denied" for my S9+.

The code below works fine for looking for any files.

```
void lookForImportFiles() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        File directory = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null).toString());
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                Log.d("Files", files[i].getName());
            }
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "External Storage Not Available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

How do I copy some test files into my Emulator's getExternalFilesdir() path from my PC?

Why is the Device File Explorer giving me "Permission denied"?

Comment: adb push <filepath> from terminal can possibly do the thing
And /storage/emulated/0 path usually simlinks to /sdcard you can check this out also

Comment: Ok - I have seen that recommendation in other places. I have never used 'adb'. Where is that? How do I get access to executing that command? This part is eluding me also.

Comment: Android Debug Bridge is console application in Android SDK. https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb

Comment: Ok - 
C:\Users\jjones\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb push C:/temp/temp.csv /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.birdersdiary.mobile/files
Produces "adb: error: cannot stat 'C:/temp/temp.csv': No such file or directory"
The file is certainly there.

Comment: C:/temp/temp.csv  I guess you're using wrong path delimeter. C:\temp\temp.csv

Comment: Good guess thekekc! I thought of that also. Both fail! But Eureka. I re-read your original comment about 'simlinks to /sdcard'. I didn't know what that meant originally and ignored it. But upon second reading, I checked; copied the file into that directory; and BAM! Now my code sees and reads the file! Thanks!!!

Comment: There seems to be several dozen ways to TRY to accomplish anything in the Android eco-system, with a myriad of answers and bits of advice to go along with each. And one never knows which is going to work until all avenues are tried.\